# Dummy View with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following piece of code in my Spring MVC application:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping")
public void ping () {

}
```

I want to respond to that request with a simple plain text with:

```
OK!
```

But I'm currently using a **ResourceBundleViewResolver**, having my jsp's in the WEB-INF/views folder... Is there a way to output plain text only by modifying the content of my ping () method? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping")
@ResponseBody
public String ping () {
   return "OK!";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another posibility:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping")
public void ping (HttpServletResponse response) {
PrintWriter out;
response.setContentType("text/plain");
try {
out = response.getWriter();
out.write(message);
}
catch (IOException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();

} finally {
  out.close();
}
}
```

If you need to return text, use what @skaffman suggested it's better aproach, if you need to return file or any other object with different content type (file or file chunk, for example) you can use this approach.

Comment: The combination of `@ResponseBody` and `void` return type makes no sense.

Comment: @skaffman, are you saying that if i'm sending something using HttpServletResponse I don't need @ResponseBody annotation? Will it work? I have never tested it.

Comment: Correct. `@ResponseBody` refers to the return value. If your controller method declares `HttpServletResponse` or `Writer` as a parameter, Spring assumes you're handling the response yourself.

Comment: Very nice tips, I'll consider them, but for my situation in only need what @skaffman proposed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the mvc namespace.
Something like
Viewname = jspfile